# How to disable the default Shadow from Xaml controls which is provided in Windows Build 1903?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, shadow, dropshadow

So, Windows build 1903 sdk has applied a default "Shadow" on certain xaml controls, as can be seen from the list.   I am using CommandBar in a project, and the "See more" button has an associated Popup with it, however I find no way to disable the shadow of it.  This shadow does not show in any other previous windows Builds. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/depth-shadow

In the microsoft's blog post regarding this, they have given out the following code to remove shadow from a flyout like object, however they did not specify any code for removing the shadow from other controls.

This particular property in the following code named "IsDefaultShadowEnabled" is only accessible from the FlyoutPresenterStyles, I have tried from other controls, such as GridView, Border, couldn't find it in there. I tried attaching this flyout with the flyoutbase associated with the command bar. but did not help.

I added the code for the commandbar I am having the shadow on.

```
  <Flyout>
       <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
           <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
               <Setter Property="IsDefaultShadowEnabled" Value="False" />
          </Style>
       </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
  </Flyout>



    <CommandBar Background="Yellow" FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="0" FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="0">
        <CommandBar.CommandBarOverflowPresenterStyle>
            <Style TargetType="CommandBarOverflowPresenter">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </CommandBar.CommandBarOverflowPresenterStyle>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>

            <AppBarButton Label="YELLOW!"/>
            <AppBarButton  Label="YELLOW!"/>
            <AppBarButton  Label="YELLOW!"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>

    </CommandBar>
```

Can you guys tell me any workaround to fix the shadow issue if there's no direct solution?

Comment: I checked the underlying implementation,command bar uses the Popup controller instead of flyout.Can you try to modify the Popup style to remove the shadow?

Comment: Modifying the Popup style did not help, but I attached a MenuFlyout with the commandbar and it worked. :)

Comment: But apparently we can't use the latest build version as the target version ... I can't use IsDefaultShadowEnabled feature... using MenuFlyout doesn't help anymore

Comment: The xaml team wants to talk to you directly. So we recommend you can open an issue on the [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/new/choose) as a bug and specify exactly what problem you have.

Comment: We finally updated our Target Version to 1903. And disabled the shadow from the MenuFlyout of CommandBar, but an interesting thing happened,  The MenuFlyout of the commandBar started to show different Border, and it would not dismiss when we clicked elsewhere.  We had to replace commandbar with basic grid to fix that.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?If you solved,you can post your answer.That would be helpful for other communities who meet the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Faywang,  I had opened an Issue at that repository you suggested, they suggested me to use SDK build version 1903. We built our project with SDK 1903, some additional issues had arisen but we fixed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With  @ Faywang - MSFT 's advice, the issue was registered in Win UI team's repository,

Mr. @jevansaks response mentioned of using SDK Build Version 1903 as the **Target version**, additionally setting the **MaxTestedVersion** to the version one tested their app on.

https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1136

In conclusion, to fix Shadows, we need to set Target Version for building app to SDK 1903, however we can set  **MaxTestedVersion** to the version we tested our app on, for instance it can be 1809.